# Component variable can't be modified in a callback method in vue.js

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, vue.js, callback, closures

I defined a `Login.vue` component in the vue.js that let's me login the user to my application through AWS Cognito. I use the `___.authenticateUser()` method to login the user and start a session with Cognito. Below is the actual code that does so:

```
export default {
  name : 'Login',
  data: function() {
    return {
      errorMessageHidden: true,
      formHidden: false,
      errorMessage: '',
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showValuesToMe: function() {
      console.log(this.errorMessageHidden)
    },
    handleLogin: function() {
      const data = {
        Username: this.email,
        Pool: userPool
      }

      const cognitoUser =  new CognitoUser(data);

      const authenticationData = {
        Username : this.email,
        Password : this.password,
      };

      function showErrorMessage(err) {
        this.errorMessageHidden = false;
        this.errorMessage = err.message;
        console.log("The method got called... errorMessageHidden = " + this.errorMessageHidden);
      }

      const authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData)

      cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        callback: showErrorMessage,
        onSuccess: function(result) {
          console.log('access token ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
        },
        onFailure: function(err) {
          this.callback(err);
        }
      });
    },

    hideErorrMessage: function() {
      this.errorMessageHidden = true;
    }
  }
}
```

The issue is, inside the `handleLogin()` function of the component, when `___.authenticateUser()` is called Cognito SDK calls either `onSuccess()` or `onFailure()` depending on the auth result from the AWS.

Inside the `onFailure()` when I try to modify the `errorMessageHidden` and `errorMessage` they can't be! It happens because the `onFailure()` method is a callback method and a closure.

To access/modify these values I defined the `function showErrorMessage(err) {...}` in the scope of closure's parent. Now I can access the values defined in `data` but still can't modify them.

Can anyone figure it out how I can change the values to make changes and show error in the browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is because you are using `function` instead of arrow functions for your callback functions. When you create a function using `function` a new scope is created and `this` is not your Vue Component anymore.

You want to do it like this:

```
handleLogin: function() {
      const data = {
        Username: this.email,
        Pool: userPool
      }

      const cognitoUser =  new CognitoUser(data);

      const authenticationData = {
        Username : this.email,
        Password : this.password,
      };

      const showErrorMessage = err => {
        this.errorMessageHidden = false;
        this.errorMessage = err.message;
        console.log("The method got called... errorMessageHidden = " + this.errorMessageHidden);
      }

      const authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData)

      cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        callback: showErrorMessage,
        onSuccess: result => {
          console.log('access token ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
        },
        onFailure: err => {
          this.callback(err);
        }
      });
    }
```

With arrow functions, you will maintain the scope of the function that is calling it, so if you are inside a Vue method and use an arrow function, inside the arrow function `this` will still be the Vue Component.

Just beware, you cannot use arrow functions as a direct property of the `methods` object. That is because Vue needs to invoke the function with the Vue Component bound to `this`, something that cannot be done with arrow functions. But besides that, you may want to start using arrow function everywhere you can, they are one of my favorite ES5 features.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Function in the this components:

```
BusEvent.$emit("CloseAllTab",check => {
  if(check == true){
    this.isShowSelectYearActive = true;
  }
});
```

Function in the other components:

```
methods: {
  CloseAllTab(check) {
    check(true);
  }
},
created() {
  BusEvent.$on("CloseAllTab",this.CloseAllTab);
},
beforeDestroy() {
  BusEvent.$on("CloseAllTab",this.CloseAllTab);
}
```